# Why does SE mess with the spacing in code blocks?

Tags: support, formatting

Why do code blocks delete double-spaces? Double-spaces are required in some code. Code blocks *should* not alter the text in them at all, because code sometimes has weird formatting.

Example: compare the source of this to the rendered version: `` sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg -l|egrep '^ii  linux-(im|he)'|awk '{print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`); sudo apt-get upgrade ``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Really nothign to do with SE and everything to do with how browsers render `<code>` tags. Double spaces (and tabs, etc) are munched down into single spaces.

If you want a proper code block, use four spaces at the beginning of the lines. This wraps the `<code>` tag in a `<pre>` which makes the browser behave more literally:

```
sudo apt-get remove $(dpkg -l|egrep '^ii  linux-(im|he)'|awk '{print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`); sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And your search is better represented by:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^ii +linux\-(im|he)[a-z\-]+[0-9]/&&!/'"$(uname -r)"'/ { print $2 }'
```

A bit longer than yours but it won't remove meta-packages and hey, three commands, not five. It's still not perfect because  in my situation, I've installed a new kernel but I'm not running on it yet. This sort of search would remove the newer kernel. Automating this stuff is dangerous.

Comment: By the way, putting 4 spaces there fails miserably, and doesn't create a code block. CTRL-K-ing only puts backticks around it.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser Click edit on my post to view the source of it. And/or see: http://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The edit button is grayed out.